# How to request nodes and relationships in a single query using batch?

Tags: rest, neo4j

I am writing driver for using neo4j.

I'd like to retrieve nodes and their relationships in a single query using the endpoint `/db/data/batch`. Is it possible ?

I have tried with the following body :

`[ 
  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "to" : "/label/Person/nodes?name=%22MyName%22",
    "id" : 1
  },
  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "to" : "{1}/relationships/all"
  }
]`

but it doesn't work... (IllegalArgumentException).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I'd try the Cypher Transactional Endpoint (http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/rest-api-transactional.html) and get the node with its relationships using a single cypher statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label by property query doesn't set the {x} headers. Because there can be many results from such a query.

As Michal suggested:

use the transactional cypher endpoint with

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:{name}})-[r]-()
RETURN n,r
```